# retrieving XML form with Python Selenium

Tags: python, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I will cut straight to the chase and question:

First off, here's my code below (it's very simple):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
el = driver.find_element_by_id("id1")
el.clear()
el.send_keys("2147000001")
el = driver.find_element_by_id("id2")
el.click()
el = driver.find_element_by_id("id3")
el.click()
textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("id4")
asd = textbox.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print asd
```

The problem I am facing is that it prints nothing. I have checked the id4 element with firebug and it's like this:

```
<textarea spellcheck="false" class="debug hint" id="id4" style="display: inline;">

&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;


&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;

org.oneandone.ipayment.fraud.wrappers.SimilarIpaymentIdsResponse {
  *ipaymentIds =&gt; org.oneandone.ipayment.fraud.IpaymentIds {
  ipaymentId =&gt; [
    0 =&gt; 80000000000
    1 =&gt; 2147000165
    2 =&gt; 2147000180
    3 =&gt; 2147000130
    4 =&gt; 2147000190
    5 =&gt; 2147000192
    6 =&gt; 2147000197
    7 =&gt; 2147000144
    8 =&gt; 2147000151
    9 =&gt; 2147000198
    10 =&gt; 2147000001
    11 =&gt; 2147000170
    12 =&gt; 2147000185
    13 =&gt; 2147000179
    14 =&gt; 2147000182
    15 =&gt; 2147000183
    16 =&gt; 2147000186
    17 =&gt; 2147000193
    18 =&gt; 2147000199
    19 =&gt; 2147000201
    20 =&gt; 2147000202
    21 =&gt; 2147000204
    22 =&gt; 2147000187
    23 =&gt; 2147000218
    24 =&gt; 2147000222
    25 =&gt; 2147000301
    26 =&gt; 2147000433
    27 =&gt; 2147000434
    28 =&gt; 2147000438
    29 =&gt; 2147000461
    30 =&gt; 2147000120
    31 =&gt; 2147000462
    32 =&gt; 2147002088
    33 =&gt; 2147002672
    34 =&gt; 2147003278
    35 =&gt; 2147000229
    36 =&gt; 2147000232
    37 =&gt; 2147000326
  ]
  __id =&gt; "0.97800600 1383227941"
}
  errorcode =&gt; 0
  additional =&gt; "Similar ipaymentIds of 2147000001 retrieved."
  __id =&gt; "

0.97788900 1383227941"
}</textarea>
```

If i try using outerHTML it prints everything but the XML. Why is that? How can I get that information which I need? It is generated via javascript.

Comment: what is this line fetching `asd = textbox.get_text()` ? Can you try and let us know?

Comment: Hi. I was unable to use textbox.get_text() (AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text')
however, i succesfuly used textbox.text -> the result was an empty line...














if i use asd = textbox.get_attribute("outerHTML") I do get a line printed which is this: 
<textarea style="display: none;" id="ipayment_ipaymentFraud_getSimilarIpaymentIds_debug" class="debug hint" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
but it doesn't include the XML I am trying to fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer to this question on my own (finally); the script needs a timeout "time.sleep(1)" before actually printing out the value because of the fact that the field is populated using jquery. 
without the timeout, the script actually grabs the innerHTML of the element before it is being populated. that is why the output is blank.